# element.scrollIntoView(scrollIntoViewOptions) in Safari and IE always scrolls to the top instead of center

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, safari, microsoft-edge, js-scrollintoview

I'm using the following call to scroll an element into view in Chrome:

```
element.scrollIntoView({
  block: 'center',
  inline: 'nearest
})
```

It works properly in Chrome, but in Safari and IE/Edge, it always scrolls as if I've used block: 'start'. Even when I try changing to block: 'end', it still scrolls that element to the top of its scrollable container.

Am I missing something?

See test code here: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1V3LQQSAKF3 (sorry it's not a plunkr, but I copied the sample from the MDN site)

Comment: According to https://caniuse.com/#feat=scrollintoview , it seems that Safari and Edge "Supports scrollIntoView with boolean parameter, but not smooth behavior option". Nice.

Comment: I know the question there was about `Window.scrollTo`, while yours is about `Element.scrollIntoView` but really, it's just the same and the two top answers [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52277287/3702797) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53672870/3702797) will help you workaround the issue.