# window.scrollTo is not smooth on Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the window.scrollTo function with behavior: 'smooth'. It indeed works well and smooth on Chrome, but on Safari it instantly scrolls instead of using the smooth animation. How can I fix that? Here is my code:

```
    function scrollToInfo(infoDiv) {
  let infoPos = $(infoDiv).offset().top;
  window.scrollTo({
    top: infoPos,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

Comment: MDN documentation of API `window.scrollTo` says that it's not compatible with Safari - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Comment: See this answer for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55221484/608170.

Comment: So it would be better if I used javascript's scrollTop i guess?

Comment: @RobertFedus if you are using jQuery anyway, jQuery is able to animate `scrollTop` quite smoothly.  Example here:  https://www.journaldev.com/wp-content/uploads/jquery/scrollTop.html.  Memory tells me that this is good cross browser, but I can't check now.

Comment: @dgo Thank you, this solved my problem.

Comment: No problem.  Glad it helped